# Create UNION ALL statements via a loop

Tags: sql, oracle

Manually, I can select partitions in an inner query with the first code block below. Is there a way to do this in a more elegant way via a loop? I'm showing 3 partitions here, but I have about 200 and the partitions are based on a date column and therefore the partition names will need to change when I run this query again at a future date.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 

        SELECT * FROM RSS_ACQ.TRX_ARQ PARTITION("SYS_P211048") UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM RSS_ACQ.TRX_ARQ PARTITION("SYS_P210329") UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM RSS_ACQ.TRX_ARQ PARTITION("SYS_P176323")

     )  TRX_ARQ
;
```

With this statement, I've created a loop that outputs the `UNION ALL` statements.

```
BEGIN
  FOR ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS IN 
      ( 
              SELECT PARTITION_NAME
              FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS
              where TABLE_OWNER = 'TABLEOWNER'
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME'
              AND PARTITION_POSITION > 123
              ORDER BY partition_position DESC 
        )      
            LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'SELECT * FROM RSS_ACQ.TRX_ARQ PARTITION(\"' 
                                             || ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS.PARTITION_NAME || '\") UNION ALL');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

And in this block, I've attempted to use the loop inside the inner query. It's not yet formatted correctly and I'll need to avoid having `UNION ALL`  for the very last partition.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
            BEGIN
            FOR ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS IN 
                  ( 
                          SELECT PARTITION_NAME
                          FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS
                          where TABLE_OWNER = 'TABLEOWNER'
                          AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME'
                          AND PARTITION_POSITION > 123
                          ORDER BY partition_position DESC 
                    )      
                        LOOP
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'SELECT * FROM RSS_ACQ.TRX_ARQ PARTITION(\"' 
      || ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS.PARTITION_NAME || '\") UNION ALL');
              END LOOP;
            END;      
     )  TRX_ARQ
;
```

Here are some of the errors, but there were also many more. They are syntax errors pointing to other parts of the query so I would expect that I have an issue with escaping the quotes.

```
Error starting at line : 99 in command -
END LOOP
Error report -
Unknown Command

Error starting at line : 100 in command -
END
Error report -
Unknown Command

Error starting at line : 101 in command -
)
Error report -
Unknown Command

Error starting at line : 102 in command -
)  TABLENAME
Error report -
Unknown Command
```

Comment: I would have approached it different, putting each of the sub selects into a temp table and selecting the result from there.

Comment: If you want to get data from all partitions, then why don't you simply use `SELECT * FROM RSS_ACQ.TRX_ARQ`? Maybe with a `WHERE` clause on the date range to let Oracle sort out which partitions are actually needed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, actually this was my first attempt, but the operations team responsible for the database told me that the query will use far fewer resources when I name the partitions explicitly. Is that not the case?

Comment: Check the execution plan and you will see - I highly doubt that with any recent (supported) Oracle version

Answer (score 2):

We can't execute an anonymous  PL/SQL block in a SELECT statement.

What you need to do is spool the output of the ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS loop to a file (or a SQL worksheet if you're using an IDE like SQL Developer). This will give you a script you can run separately after editing it (you need to trim  UNION ALL from the final generated SELECT.

Probably there are more elegant ways of achieving the same thing, but the task seems sufficiently wrong that it doesn't strike me as being worth the effort. You want to query 200 partitions in a single statement. That is a brute force operation and there isn't mush to be gained from querying named blocks. In fact, producing a union of 200 separate queries may be more expensive than a single query. So why not try something like this?

```
select * from RSS_ACQ.TRX_ARQ
where partition_key_col >= date '2018-08-01' -- or whatever
```

---

> "I think you are overlooking the 12c feature of using PL/SQL in the WITH clause"

That 12c feature is for **functions** not procedures, so it won't help the OP run their code. It would be possible to use a WITH clause function but that would require:

- creating a type with the same projection as the target table
- and a nested table type based on that type
- a WITH clause function which assembles and executes a dynamic SQL statement
- we can't use REF CURSORs in SQL so ...
- the function has to execute the dynamic select INTO a local collection variable ...
- then loop over the collection and PIPE ROW to output those rows ...
- so the main query can call the function with a `table()` call

Can a WITH clause function be pipelined? I can't find anything in the documentation to say we can't (don't have access to 12c right now to test).

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - actually I didn't overlook it, I deliberately discounted it. But just to humour you I have written up the steps necessary to implement the OP's approach using a WITH clause function.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a guess, but it's too long for a comment.

I am assuming your table is interval partitioned.  In that case, getting all the data from partition positions > 123 is the same as getting all the rows with a higher date than the highest date in partition 123.

You can obtain that date from `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS` and then use it to query the table.  Like this:

```
WITH FUNCTION get_high_value RETURN DATE IS 
  l_high_val_expr ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS.HIGH_VALUE%TYPE;
  l_high_value DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT high_value
  INTO   l_high_val_expr
  FROM   all_tab_partitions 
  WHERE  table_owner = 'RSS_ACQ'
  AND    table_Name = 'TRX_ARQ'
  and    partition_position = 123; 

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || l_high_val_expr || ' FROM DUAL' INTO l_high_value;

  RETURN l_high_value;
END;
SELECT * FROM rss_acq.trx_arq
-- Replace "partitioned_date_column" with the name of the column on which the
-- table is interval partitioned.
WHERE partitioned_date_column > get_high_value;
```

Comment: This seems like a complicated way of getting to my *"why not try something like this"* solution? I agree it means we don't need to know the starting value of the partitioned key. But in real life I think it's more likely that we will know the lower bound of a date range than the PARTITION_POSITION for the partition storing that date.

Comment: @APC Yes, real life is like that.  But the OP's code used the PARTITION_POSITION as input.  I assumed he's doing something unusual and outside the scope of the question, otherwise he would just select from the table using the date range he already knows.